# Get neighbors of each leaf given the linkage matrix

Tags: python, scipy

A linkage matrix can be converted to ClusterNode or Dendrogram. However, I have no idea how to get the neighbors of each leaf with a simple method.

Given an example shown as follows, I would like to get the neighbors of all leaves. The expected result is {A: [B], B: [A], C: [D, E, F], D: [E, F], E: [F], F: [E]}

[image]

Comment: have you found the solution?